# Trouble printing JSON Object from tree

Tags: java, json, tree

I have an issue where I want to print JSONObjects and JSONArrays from a tree. The problem arises when I want to print the children.

```
public class program {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("");
    File outputfile = new File("");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputfile, true)));

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object object = parser.parse(new FileReader(file));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;

        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("declaration-list");

        try {


            Iterator iterator = jsonArray.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
                String variableName = (String) jo.get("declared-variable");
                MyTreeNode<String> root = new MyTreeNode<>(variableName);

                try {


                    long value = (long) jo.get("value");

                    MyTreeNode<Long> child1 = new MyTreeNode(value);

                    System.out.println(root.getData());

                    root.addChild(child1);

                    for (MyTreeNode node : root.getChildren()) {
                        System.out.println(node.getData());
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    final JSONObject jsonValue = (JSONObject) jo.get("value");

                    final String operator = (String) jsonValue.get("operator");
                    final JSONArray arguments = (JSONArray) jsonValue.get("arguments");

                    if (operator.equals("set")) {

                        MyTreeNode<JSONArray> test1 = new MyTreeNode(arguments);
                        root.addChild(test1);

                        for (MyTreeNode node : root.getChildren()) {
                            System.out.print(root.getData() + " = ");
                            System.out.println(node.getData());
                        }
                    }

                    if (operator.equals("pair")) {

                        MyTreeNode<JSONArray> test2 = new MyTreeNode(arguments);
                        root.addChild(test2);

                        for (MyTreeNode node : root.getChildren()) {
                            System.out.print(root.getData() + " = ");                               

                            System.out.println(node.getData());
                        }

                    }


                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Oops for now");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Input file not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("File was not parsed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();

}

}
```

This is just a standard tree implementation I've been using.

```
class MyTreeNode<T> {
private T data = null;
private List<MyTreeNode> children = new ArrayList<>();
private MyTreeNode parent = null;

public MyTreeNode(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void addChild(MyTreeNode child) {
    child.setParent(this);
    this.children.add(child);
}

public void addChild(T data) {
    MyTreeNode<T> newChild = new MyTreeNode<>(data);
    newChild.setParent(this);
    children.add(newChild);
}

public void addChildren(List<MyTreeNode> children) {
    for (MyTreeNode t : children) {
        t.setParent(this);
    }
    this.children.addAll(children);
}

public List<MyTreeNode> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public T getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}

private void setParent(MyTreeNode parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public MyTreeNode getParent() {
    return parent;
}

}
```

When I print the children of the root node, I keep getting results like this: [0,4]. Ideally, I would like to print the child as (0,4) due to this representing a set. I know I need to overwrite .toString, but how can I do this, when I don't pass arguments in the tree class.

Here is an example of the JSON file:

```
{
"declaration-list" : [
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x0",
        "value" : 1
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x212",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "pair",
            "arguments" : [
                1,
                2
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x213",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "pair",
            "arguments" : [
                3,
                4
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x3",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "set",
            "arguments" : [
                {
                    "variable" : "x212"
                  },
                {
                    "variable" : "x213"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x214",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "pair",
            "arguments" : [
                0,
                4
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x215",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "pair",
            "arguments" : [
                1,
                6
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x10",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "set",
            "arguments" : [
                {
                    "variable" : "x214"
                  },
                {
                    "variable" : "x215"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x216",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "set",
            "arguments" : [
                8
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x8",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "set",
            "arguments" : [
                {
                    "variable" : "x216"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x217",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "set",
            "arguments" : [
                {
                    "variable" : "x8"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x8",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "set",
            "arguments" : [
                {
                    "variable" : "x8"
                  },
                {
                    "variable" : "x217"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x17",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "set",
            "arguments" : [
                1,
                2,
                {
                    "variable" : "x8"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x218",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "pair",
            "arguments" : [
                1,
                {
                    "variable" : "x17"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x18",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "set",
            "arguments" : [
                {
                    "variable" : "x17"
                  },
                {
                    "variable" : "x218"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x19",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "pair",
            "arguments" : [
                {
                    "variable" : "x18"
                  },
                {
                    "variable" : "x17"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
    {
        "declared-variable" : "x219",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "set",
            "arguments" : [
                0
              ]
          }
      },

    {
        "declared-variable" : "x221",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "set",
            "arguments" : [
                {
                    "variable" : "x219"
                  },
                {
                    "variable" : "x220"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },

    {
        "declared-variable" : "x224",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "set",
            "arguments" : [
                2,
                1
              ]
          }
      },

    {
        "declared-variable" : "x225",
        "value" : {
            "operator" : "set",
            "arguments" : [
                {
                    "variable" : "x19"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
  ]
```

}

Comment: could you paste an example json file?

Comment: @gybandi Of course. I have updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this, is to write a wrapper class with a custom toString() method where you define how you want to output the elements of the JSONArray.

This could look something like this:

```
public class MyArrayNode {

    private JSONArray array;

    public MyArrayNode(JSONArray array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public JSONArray getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",", "(", ")");
        array.forEach(a -> sj.add(a.toString()));
        return sj.toString();
    }
}
```

If you want to print out a JSONArray like this, simply make your MyTreeNode 
contain MyArrayNode type elements:

```
      final JSONArray arguments = (JSONArray) jsonValue.get("arguments");
      if (operator.equals("set")) {
         MyTreeNode<MyArrayNode> test1 = new MyTreeNode(new MyArrayNode(arguments));
```

Comment: It's not quite done what I wanted it to do, but I was able to use your answer to help me get it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is sort of a crude answer, but you could add the following method or something similar to your MyTreeNode class. If you know any class of type `T` is going to be in the format of "[x,y]" when calling getData(), this will work:

```
void printData() {
    String t = (String)getData();
    t.replace("[", "(");
    t.replace("]", ")");
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

EDIT: Updated code from your comment's clarification:

```
void printData() {
    String t = (String)getData();
    if(t.startsWith("{") && t.endsWith("}")) {
        t.replace("{", "(");
        t.replace("}", ")");
    }
    else if(t.startsWith("[") && t.endsWith("]")) {
        t.replace("[", "(");
        t.replace("]", ")");
    }
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry I'd actually mucked up my question a little. I have a problem where the children can be sets {x,y} and they can also be pair (x,y) and I need to be able to distinguish between the 2. I had thought of something similar to yourself, but I'm not sure how I'd be able to distinguish between the 2 that way?

Comment: Infact, that doesn't work. It get's caught in my try catch and throws an error.